# When i execute the following code in pl/sql developer it throws a error?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
**create or replace procedure Xml_Table is
begin
  DECLARE
 l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN

 SELECT XMLELEMENT("employees",
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT("employee",
               XMLFOREST(
                 e.empno AS "empno",
                 e.ename AS "ename",
                 e.job AS "job",
                 TO_CHAR(e.hiredate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS "hiredate"
               )
             )
           ) 
         )
  INTO   l_xmltype
  FROM   emp e;
  INSERT INTO xml_tab VALUES (1, l_xmltype);
  COMMIT;
end Xml_Table;**
```

In this Xml_Table is the procedure i have created . and Xml_tab is the table of xml datatype i have created in the database. One more question is there a way i can create a procedure pl/sql in which i can drop and create new xml type table instead of doing it outside the procedure.

ERROR MESSAGE:Compilation errors for PROCEDURE APPS.XML_TABLE

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

```
      ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
      null pragma raise return select update while with
      <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
      <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
      insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
      merge pipe purge
```

Comment: Remove both lines 1 and 2 and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
create or replace procedure Xml_Table as
/*
begin --> REMOVE
DECLARE --> REMOVE
*/
 l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: Thank you very it worked .Is there a way u can include CREATE AND DROP the XML table in the procedure.

Comment: You can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:    execute immediate 'drop table mytable'; execute immediate 'create table mytable (column 1 integer, etc etc)';. Please vote and/or accept the answer.